# Solving Definite Integrals

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Suppose that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are two continuous and differentiable functions. Suppose also that
\begin{align}
  \alpha'(x) &= \beta(x),  \\ 
  \beta(x)^3 &= (α(x) − 1)^2,  \\
  \alpha(a) &= 0, \text{and }  \\
  \alpha(b) &= 2
\end{align}
Using this information, compute the definite integral
$$
  \int_a^b{\alpha(t)^2 \beta(t)^4 \,dt}
$$
Ive gotten this far just not sure what my next step should be!

[My work so far (link)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fkwE.png)

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The exercise gives $\alpha'(x) = \beta(x)$, which implies substitution. You need to write the integrand in a form that can be evaluated with substitution. First, notice that $\color{blue}{\beta^3(x) = \left[\alpha(x)-1\right]^2}$:

$$\int_{a}^{b} \alpha^2(x)\beta^4(x) \mathrm dx = \int_{a}^{b} \alpha^2(x)\color{blue}{\beta^3(x)}\beta(x)\mathrm dx = \int_{a}^{b} \alpha^2(x)\color{blue}{\left[\alpha(x)-1\right]^2}\beta(x)\mathrm dx$$

Now, since $\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx} [\alpha(x)] = \beta(x) \iff \mathrm d[\alpha(x)] = \beta(x) \mathrm dx$, you can let $u = \alpha(x)$. This means $\mathrm du = \beta(x)\mathrm dx$, and the bounds of integration become $\alpha(a)$ and $\alpha(b)$:

$$\int_{u = \alpha(a)}^{u = \alpha(b)} u^2(u-1)^2\mathrm du = \int_{0}^{2} u^2(u-1)^2\mathrm du$$

The rest is just expanding and simplifying.

Comment: thank you for clarifying this. It makes sense now!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help!